# Lazy Loading in getorgchart

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, getorgchart

I have applied getorgchart jquery plugin  in my code, I have huge data and want to call child nodes on demand,

How to apply lazyLoading in getorgchart jquery plugin , is there are build in APIs to maintain this?

Comment: What have you tried so far, please show us

Comment: We add the plugin as is, as per documentation, however , we did not find any API regarding lazyloading!

Comment: I dont know how big your data is, but i use org chart for a client, that company has over 2000 employees and my org chart loads quick, 1-2 sec max

Comment: more than 3000 records and page is interactive between multiple users. they can add and delete @ same time

Comment: For what you describe I don't think there is any api or code that supports what you want, guess you have to write it yourself.

Comment: The Question is , are there any such feature , if anyone  know please advise